# How does SSAS server process cubes?

Tags: ssas

I don't have much experience with SSAS cubes. We have an SSAS Visual Studio package that contains three cubes (see below). When these cubes are processed by our SSAS server, are the cubes processed sequentially or are they (or can they be) processed in parallel, to reduce processing time?

[image]

Comment: It depends entirely on the command submitted to the server. Pieces of the cube (dimensions or partitions) can be processed sequentially or in parallel. How do you process these now?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Thanks Nick. Can you tell me how or where this setting is controlled?

Comment: You request the server to process some component of your cube. One way to perform this request is to submit XMLA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/schedule-ssas-administrative-tasks-with-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UlrhCAA_48

Comment: Connect to your SSAS Server, right click on a dimension and process. Press _script_. You get an XMLA script. You can add other dimensions to this script. If you tuck them all inside the _parallel_ tags, they'll process in parallel

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Thanks very much Nick. If you wrap this up in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: OK. Tomorrow when I'm at work if I have time I'll get some code samples. I'm sure this has probably already been answered on here but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check what is happening when you process a dimension / cube / Analysis database, you should use a tool named "sql server profiler". When you start it, it captures all queries/ events that happen in your SQL Server. You need to be sys_admin of the instance though.

Concerning the way SSAS works to process, the engine determine by himself how many threads it can use for parallelism depending of many parameters (number of core of your machine for example). Some parameters can be redefined in the instance parameters but I don't advice you to touch it without strong knowledge.

Hope it helps !